# Calling JavaScript from the parent window

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

I am very new to JavaScript as well as JSP.

I have a JSP page. In that JSP page, I have one text box to enter the URL, `submit` button and `Extract` button. I also embedded `iframe` in that JSP page. When I enter a URL in the text box and press `submit` button, the page is loaded in the `iframe`. It's working fine.

Now I would like to run another JavaScript on the loaded `iframe` (which has a web page) when pressing `Extract` button. How can I do it? Please help me out in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

try document.iframes[frameName].document.yourMethod() or document.iframes[frameName].yourMethod()

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can do something like this in your iframe.

```
window.top.yourJS_Object.your_iframe_callback();
```

while `yourJS_Object` can also be any method as well. it's just an example.
and to access the ifram:

`window.frames.<frameName>.document.getElementById('result');` i.e.

but it has to be the same domain as far as i know.